# <!DOCTYPE HTML> declaration causes div contents to NOT display

Tags: php, jquery, html, doctype

I have an html page which contains a div that displays the html from an external php file.
It works great until I add a DOCTYPE declaration to the html page. The page continues to function, except the external content does not appear in the div.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>

<title>Test Page</title>

<!--meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="./inc/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getinfo()
        {
        $.post('prodinfo.php', { prodcode: prodcodeform.prodcodevar.value},
            function(output)
            {
            $('#prodinfo').html(output).show;
            });
        }

    function hideinfo()
        {
        $('#prodload').hide();
        $('#openprodinfo').show();
        }

    function showinfo()
        {
        $('#prodload').show();
        $('#openprodinfo').hide();
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input style="position:relative;" type="button" class="button" id="openprodinfo" title="Open" value="INFO" onclick="showinfo();">
<DIV id="prodload" style="position:absolute;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:none;text-align:center;background-color:#000000;z-index:200;border:1px solid #4e443b;">

    <div id="prodinfo" style="position:relative;display:block;top:0;width:1000px;height:820px;background-color:#ffffff;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
    </div>

    <form name="prodcodeform">
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="prodcodevar" name="prodcodevar" value="nil" >
    </form>

    <div ID="prodinfobutton" style="position:relative;">
    <input  style="position:relative;" type="button" class="button" id="closeprodinfo" title="Close" value="CLOSE" onclick="document.getElementById('prodcodevar').value='nil'; hideinfo(); ">
    </div>

    <input type="button" id="button001" value="ONE" onclick="document.getElementById('prodcodevar').value='item1'; getinfo();">

    <input type="button" id="button002" value="TWO" onclick="document.getElementById('prodcodevar').value='item2'; getinfo();">


</DIV>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to validate your code : http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: This is because you were rendering in quirks mode and when you added the doctype it rendered in strict mode. You should validate your code and fix any errors you find.

Comment: Have you tried lower-casing the `<DIV>`?

Comment: Indented curlybraces are horrible to read...

Comment: The code validates, lower case makes no difference, and I like indented curlybraces. But Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are switching to Standards mode, so your browser is no longer playing the game of being compatible with Internet Explorer 4.

`prodcodeform.prodcodevar.value` will error because `prodcodeform` is undefined.

You don't get a global variable for every element with an id or name in a document.

Change:

```
<form name="prodcodeform">
```

To

```
<form id="prodcodeform" method="post" action="prodinfo.php">
```

… and make it do something sane when a non-Ajax request gets posted (move it so it is around the buttons, make them submit buttons, and cancel the default event if the JS succeeds).

Then add:

```
var prodcodeform = document.getElementById('prodcodeform');
```

before you try to use the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but your suggested changes made no difference.

Comment: Now that I have read your ENTIRE Answer, and declared the variable as you suggested, it works! Sorry, but in my haste I missed that critical step.

Answer (score 0):

You started your body with `</body>` instead of `<body>`.

Comment: Wow you are fast! I fixed that a minute after posting and you still caught it.